# Child form closed on enter click

Tags: c#, winforms, keyup

I have two Forms `Frm1` and `Frm2`.

Both having single `textbox`.

On `keyup` event of first form `textbox`, second form is opened if `KeyChar` is `ENTER`.

Now on `KeyUp` event for `textbox` in 2nd form I am closing this form **i.e** submitting.

Now both events are called. Is there any way to get rid of thi?

```
 private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                Frm2 frm=new Frm2();
                Frm2.RefToForm1=this;
                frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                frm.ShowDialog(this);
            }

        }
```

Now in second form

```
private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
               this.RefToForm1.textBox1.Text=textBox2.Text;
                this.Close()
            }

        }
```

Problem is when I press enter on `textBox1` , `form2` is opened and closed immediately.

Any Solutions

Comment: you could keep a boolean in 2nd form and close the form based on its value. e.g initially define it to false and set it to true later when you need it.

Comment: but where can i set this value to true i.e on which event. I am passing value from 1st to 2nd textbox

Comment: Is `RefToForm1` static?

Comment: Then what is this `Frm2.RefToForm1=this;` ? How are you assigning `form1` reference directly to class property `Frm2.RefToForm1` without instantiating it?

Comment: @Nitin Varpe i am not sure but there must be some method for texbox focus e.g onFocus or something like that. you could set it to true inside that.

Comment: no there isnt focus event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the windows form property for-

1- `AcceptButton` - button id ( on which button you have to submit.)
2-`CancelButton` -  button id ( on which button you have to close the form.)

Answer (score 1):

define a boolean variable in form 2, set it to false initially and close the form based on that variable. You could set it to true later when you need it. You could use the GotFocus method of the textbox to set to it true. e.g

```
    textBox2.GotFocus += textBox2_GotFocus;
```

Set the boolean to true inside the textBox2_GotFocus method. Your key_up method would look like this :

```
    private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
           if(boolean_var){
               this.RefToForm1.textBox1.Text=textBox2.Text;
               this.Close();
           }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that releasing the Enter key when `textBox1` is focused and no instance of `Frm2` is opened yet, would also raise the `KeyUp` event on `textBox2` in `Frm2`.

Are you sure you don't have some addition code in your project that's causing this behavior? Did you try putting a breakpoint on `this.Close()` in `textBox2_GotFocus` method to see if it actually gets executed in your scenario?

I even created a small sample project using your code with some minor modifications to make it work (explained in comments):

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Frm2 frm=new Frm2();
        frm.RefToForm1=this; // you said RefToForm1 isn't static and it shouldn't be
        frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        frm.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}

private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.RefToForm1.textBox1.Text=textBox2.Text;
        this.Close(); // missing semicolon
    }
}

public Form1 RefToForm1 { get; set; } // property in Frm2
```

You can download this working sample project from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10676122/20866648-KeyUp.zip).

Comment: Yes i have checked by putting breakpoint. I dont know what solution are u giving really?

Comment: I guess, most people will get a correct result trying to run solely those two code blocks (event handler for textbox1 & textbox2 keyUp event). I also tried the codes and form2 behave as expected (It doesn't close until I press enter again). So as @Damir suggested you may need to debug further and check if any other portion of your codes triggering that false behavior as you stated in question..

Comment: @NitinVarpe When my sample starts, `Form1` opens with focus in `textBox1`. You press Enter and `Frm2` opens with focus in `textBox2`. It remains open until you press Enter again, then it closes. Maybe I didnt understand you correctly, but wasn't your problem that `Frm2` just closed immediately?

Comment: thanx @DamirArh , i have solved issue with properties of form acceptbutton

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could prevent the second form from closing if the textbox is empty -- assuming something needs to go in there for it to close.

Could you give us more information about what you're trying to do with this? Perhaps there's another way to solve the feature you're trying to create.

Comment: Actually i am passing value from txt1 to txt2, so cant check for empty string

Comment: And my project is bigger. i have only stated one scenario. there are many checks to know which form to open